# Delphi7 - How can i find where my project is hanging the compiler?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, ide

I have a project in Delphi7. Its is rather large consisting of 40 odd forms and frames.
Recently, the compiler only allows me to compile the project once so i can run it, then every re-compile the IDE hangs and i have to end the Delphi process. Before this occurs, my CPU goes to 50% (on dual core machine) so my deduction is the compilation process has gone into an infinite loop. The Executable it produces is not runnable and usually at a fixed size after it hangs.

I was wondering how i can go about finding where this inconsistency in my project is. Other projects do not suffer from this same issue.

Comment: More information: So ive run it now for an hour or so with no crashes. Cant see what ive changed - i dont think its my code. Yes i am using version control - but is there any way to see in the corrupt exe which part of my app it was compiling at the time of the crash?

Comment: da-soft's suggestion of using Process Explorer might pinpoint you the file the compiler is working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "process of elimination", to see if it's something in your code.

First, make a backup of where you are, or save to your CVS (you ARE using version control, right? RIGHT? good.)  Revert your branch to an earlier version where it worked.  See if that works.  If so, merge half of the changes from the present-day version. If that works, try the other half. Keep cutting things in half, and you'll find the code that causes the problem, by process of elimination.

Or, it may turn out to be something in the configuration. Carbonite may be your friend here.

Comment: Yes i reverted back to an earlier version which didnt crash. By process of elimination i found the problematic code. Unfortunately not an easy process!

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to discover what compiler is doing (reading a file, or ...).
2. Check the [QC 3807](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=3807) issue.
3. Check the system resources - free disk space, memory. Clean the temp folder. Check the disk for errors. Do you have antivirus running ? If yes, then try to turn it off.

Comment: I like the process explorer idea.

Comment: Tried to use process explorer to see the open handles during the compile. On successful compile i can see the files in use. However on the unsuccessful compile, no file handles were shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Enable "Compilation progress display" in the "Environment Options" window, in the "Preferences" tab.
2. Use the command line compiler bcc32.exe to have a detailed console output.

Both will let you know which file is hanging the compiler.

Take a look at the great [Delphi Speed Up](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/delphispeedup/) tool, which allows e.g. to abort CodeCompletion and HelpInsight by ESC/mouse move.

Comment: Yes, i am using the Speed up tool. Makes a difference!

Comment: the compilation progress display unfortunately doesnt display each individual file - rather the dpr project file. The failed compilation occurs during the 'Linking' phase.